# Why the .get call has a default mvc controller with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am writing a javascript with jquery.
I do a get request to the server with test as controller and xhrGetListing as method.
Let my domain be https://example.com

```
 $.get('test/xhrGetListing', function(o){
    
    for(var i=0; i < o.length; i++)
    {
        alert(1);
        $('#listInsert').append(o[i].id);
    }
    
    
    
, 'json'}

$('#randomInsert').submit(function(){
    
    var url = $(this).attr('action');    //test/xhrInsert
    
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    
    $.post(url, data, function(o){
        
    });
    
    return false;
});
```

However, it sends the request to https://example.com/test/test/xhrGetListing.
The xhrInsert call is fine

Comment: Use `'/test/xhrGetListing'` as the url. Your <form> probably does this? Relative URLs are appended to the current location, so if you're looking at `http://localhost/test/` in the browser, getting `test/xhrGetListing` will request the wrong URL.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works so fine <3